# When drag window between MacOS (Monterey) monitors, window is underneath

Tags: macos, windows, window-manager

I am new to MacOS and this maybe standard behaviour when moving windows between monitors.

1. I cannot drag maximised windows between monitors by left-clicking and dragging the window menu bar. I have to click window's green button then I can drag the window between monitors. Is this standard behaviour? Is there any way to drag a maximized window without first clicking on the green button?
2. When I drag a window between monitors and the target monitor has one or more maximized windows, the dragged window is dragged **under** the maximized window. Again I have to have no windows maximized on the target monitor to drag a window on **top** of the open windows on the target. Is there a setting in MacOS where when I drag a window from one monitor to another monitor, the dragged window is automatically placed on **top** of all other windows on the target? This is the behaviour in Windows(TM).

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a full-screen window, not a maximized window.  Full-screen windows are always on top.

If you want to be able to layer windows, do not full-screen them.

You can option-click the green control to maximize a window.